# Extract value from an ID tag in a extracted Html data

Tags: firefox, imacros

I hope my topic finds you well.

I want to extract a specific number from an ID value,

here is the line:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=CLASS:markAll<SP>check EXTRACT=HTM
```

and here is the result I get after I run the previous line:

```
<input style="outline: 1px solid blue;" id="raidListMarkAll1518" class="markAll check" onclick="Game.RaidList.markAllSlotsOfAListForRaid(1518, this.checked); "type="checkbox">
```

For example, I want only to extract this number (**1518**) from this (id="raidListMarkAll**1518**").

I don't know how to make the EVAL command to achieve the result I want.

I hope to get help from you guys, I really appreciate it

Thank you so much.